# xubuntu 23.10 ISO files with two md5sum errors

Tags: xubuntu, iso

I extracted the files from *xubuntu-23.10-desktop-amd64.iso*.
The file *md5sum.txt* contains a list of the files with the md5sum values.
Result of
`md5sum -c md5sum.txt`:

```
...
./.disk/info: OK
./.disk/casper-uuid-generic: OK
./.disk/release_notes_url: OK
md5sum: WARNING: 2 computed checksums did NOT match
```

The two bad files:

```
./dists/mantic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: FAILED
./dists/mantic/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz: FAILED
```

NB. The value of sh256sum on the .iso file is correct.

```
sha256sum  xubuntu-23.10-desktop-amd64.iso 
d5e03f6f14a9dbbfd53072471dd96af7360c8ac5609f0909de77cc858fd69b6c  xubuntu-23.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Perhaps a last minute change in the prepared files?

Comment: Once 23.10 was created, **that was it**, there was no revisions.  If you have bad files in the ISO during its self-verification then despite the SHA sum of the ISO, you need to obtain another copy of the ISO and use that.  Any failure in the ISO to validate its own files indicates a "failed copy of the ISO"

Comment: I find the writing of ISOs to USB-flash-media the most problematic stage, was this an ISO written to media?  (I find 3-5% failure rate using sandisk, higher with other brands). I've actually used the Xubuntu ISOs myself, and all checks passed when I checked the media self validation (*that's something I've done a number of times as I'm involved in some QA*)

Comment: You can check the final step: cloning to the USB flash media according to [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=62&p=14142910#post14142910) at the Ubuntu Forums.

Answer (score -1):

Now I found the cause.
Yesterday I used    **open with "Archive Manager"** to extract the files.
Today I wanted to enter all commands manually.
I used the **mount -o loop** which I saw in
[3 Ways to Extract and Copy Files from ISO Image in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/extract-files-from-iso-files-linux/)
And  now `md5sum -c md5sum.txt` worked without errors.

Comparing the files I noticed that the extract command in the archive manager changed the two files, which then failed with `md5sum`.\

```
mkdir files
sudo mount -o loop xubuntu-23.10-desktop-amd64.iso files/
 
mount: /home/xxxx/xubuntu/test/files: WARNING: source write-protected, mounted read-only.

~/xubuntu/test$ cmp ./dists/mantic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz files/dists/mantic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
cmp: EOF on ./dists/mantic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz which is empty
ls -lat ./dists/mantic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz files/dists/mantic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
-r--r--r-- 1 xxxx xxxx  0 Okt 10 06:07 ./dists/mantic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
-r--r--r-- 3 root root 40 Okt 10 06:07 files/dists/mantic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
```